# Calculate netmask from list of IP's

Tags: python, math, networking

I have a list of IPv4 addresses that are all on the same network. I would like to calculate a netmask for that network given the list of IP's.

List:

```
192.168.2.2
192.168.2.3
192.168.2.4
```

Resulting netmask: 255.255.255.0

Current algorithm: If octets differ place a `0` in that netmask position, else place `255`.

```py
prev_ip = None
current_netmask = [255,255,255,255]
for ip in ip_list:
  if prev_ip != None:
    for i in range(0,4):
      if ip.split('.')[i] != prev_ip.split('.')[i]:
        current_netmask[i] = 0
  prev_ip = ip
```

My issue is that this netmask is not always correct, and I know other netmasks are possible (other than ones comprised of 0's and 255's)

Comment: That is not the longest mask for those three addresses. The correct answer would be `255.255.255.248`. Trying to manipulate IP addresses in text is a fool's game. IPv4 addresses are 32-bit unsigned integers, and you need to do the math. There is a section in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) that explains how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work. Converts addresses to integers, starts with a mask of all 1s and will progressively zero increasing bits starting at the least significant while the IPs differ when bitwise and-ed with the mask.  (Each new IP only needs to be compared with one of the IPs already considered, because by that stage the mask already reflects the comparison with the other IPs considered, hence the line with `vals[0]`.)   Finally it converts the mask back to dotted quad representation.

```
def to_int(ip):
    bytes = [int(s) for s in ip.split(".")]
    return sum(val<<(8*i) for i, val in enumerate(reversed(bytes)))

def from_int(val):
    r = []
    while val:
        r.append(val & 0xFF)
        val >>= 8
    if len(r) < 4:
        r.extend([0] * (4-len(r)))
    return ".".join(map(str, reversed(r)))

def get_mask(ips):
    vals = [to_int(ip) for ip in ips]
    mask = 0xFFFFFFFF
    bit = 1
    for val in vals[1:]:
        while vals[0] & mask != val & mask:
            mask &= ~bit
            bit <<= 1
    return from_int(mask)

ips = ["192.168.2.2", "192.168.2.3", "192.168.2.4"]
print(get_mask(ips))
```

gives:

```
255.255.255.248
```

Comment: There is probably a neater solution with the `ipaddress` package, but to be honest it was quicker to write something from scratch than learn how to use it. Maybe someone else can provide another answer along those lines.

Comment: @AnnZen right bit shift assignment `val >>= 8` is equivalent to `val //= 2**8` (at least for positive numbers)